# ExpandoObject, convert to static

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, expandoobject

FromBody I get an object that has a property that is showing up in debugger, but when i try to add this property to the object it would cause a circular dependancy. This is why I'm trying to convert this object to ExpandoObject and after doing my staff, i wanted to convert it back to the type i got from FromBody. I tried serializing the ExpandoObject and decentralizing it back to the type i got from FromBody and it doesn't work. What alternatives do I have?

The Object:

```
public class Blob
{
    public BlobBlob BlobBlob { get; set; }
}

public class BlobBlob 
{
    [JsonProperty] public List<BlobStep> BlobSteps{ get; set; } = new List<BlobStep>();
    public BlobBlob (BlobStep step) : this()
    {
        BlobSteps.Add(step);
    }

}

public class BlobStep {
    [JsonProperty] public List<ICommand> Commands { get; private set; } = new List<ICommand>();
}

public interface ICommand {
    //here is a property that is causing a circular dependancy, but if i dont mention it in ICommand it still shows up in debugger 
}
```

The code i wrote for decerialization that causes errors

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
    };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(step, settings);
dynamic stepDynamic =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(ExpandoObject), settings);

//some manipulations with ExpandoObject


var jsonBlobObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stepDynamic, settings);
var stepDynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Blob>(jsonBlobObject, settings);
```

Comment: The Expando Object is basically a `Dictionary<string, object>` with some Syntax sugar for easier access. It throws compile time type safety out of the window. If you interact with a weakly typed WebService (like any written in PHP), they are a nessesary evil: You transfer whatever you get as return into a expando object as first - then you decide which actuall, strongly typed .NET class should be instantiated to take over the data.

Comment: The issue with circular dependencies seems unrelated to deserialization and dynamic data. Circular Dps are usually solved be relocating the type in question classes to a common, shared assembly  - or sometimes to the assembly where the cdp occurs.